# How to use sumifs comparison operators with range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, sumifs

I am looking to compare the values in two columns on a row by row basis and sum the values in one of those columns based on the results of the comparison.

Something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(T4:T50,T4:T50,">="&M4:M50)
```

Here, I am comparing the values in columns T and M. And if for each row, the value in T is more than M, then include in the sum.  It doesn't work.

But something like this works:

```
=SUMIFS(T4:T50,T4:T50,">=400")
```

How can I compare on a row by row basis?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful post that includes 6 options for this problem: [How to Include Multiple Sum Columns in SUMIF in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-include-multiple-sum-columns-in-sumif-in-google-sheets/)

I tend to prefer option #1 of using helper columns because it makes for shorter formulas, and it is easier for someone else (or even yourself) to retrace your steps later on.

So in your case, I would add a helper column that is simply:

```
=T4 >= M4
```

Copy the formula down the column. Then add the helper column as a condition in your `SUMIFS` formula:

```
=SUMIFS(T4:T50,[Helper Column],TRUE)
```

Comment: EDIT - Corrected error in the final `SUMIFS` formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine row-by-row comparison with a sum in a query:

```
=query({M:M,T:T},"select sum(Col2) where Col2>=Col1 label sum(Col2) 'Total'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(T2:T>=M2:M, T2:T+M2:M, ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses. each one worked but  opted to go with this:

```
SUMPRODUCT((T4:T)*((T4:T)>=(M4:M)))
```